# Swift 3 - NSButton appears but refuse to disappear

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton

I am building a single viewController app which contains around 30 buttons.
Some of them makes other buttons disappear.
Everything works well except for one of them which does not makes other buttons disappears. inside the action of this button, I use the following code:

```
if bouttonEcoute.isHidden == false
                {
                print ("false")
                bouttonEcoute.title = ""
                bouttonEcoute.isHidden = true
                }
```

"false" is printed as output but the buttons does not disappears.
I have clean the /DerivedData folder, restart the program, nothing change and I don't know what have I done wrong. Maybe someone here does? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share all of your code?

Comment: Does the title change?

Comment: No, it is impossible to publish all the code (10 pages). No, the title does not change.

Comment: if I add "bouttonEcoute.isEnabled = false" inside the loop, then the button is disabled, but refuse to disappears. I am using emoji as button icon, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I replaced the emoji by a image and now it works.